# Is it possible to suppress changefeed for certain transactions in RethinkDB?

Tags: nosql, rethinkdb

I am using RethinkDB changefeeds and sometimes when I run some queries in the backend for maintenance that affects tens of thousands of documents, the changefeed listeners can get flooded with changes that can cause major performance impact in the server.

Some of these updates are such that they don't need to be watched for changes (removing deprecated keys, updating the type of a field that is not actively used) or changes to documents that aren't currently active (past, expired, completed, not valid until a future date) when performing maintenance. Is there a way to suppress changefeed on certain queries? Something like this?

```
r.db("db").table("table").filter({"type":"INACTIVE"}).update({"type":"INVALID"}).suppressChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a [filter](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter) on the changes stream when you set it up.

In the following example it is setup to filter new_val with a score greater than the old_val

```js
r.table('scores').changes().filter(
    r.row('new_val')('score').gt(r.row('old_val')('score'))
)('new_val').run(conn, callback)
```